# Python API troubles

Tags: python, api

I've been tasked with learning Python on the spot and feel like I'm drowning. I am trying to translate what was provided by a coworker but am really struggling. The API I am trying to work with is here: https://dev.skuvault.com/v1.0/reference#getonlinesalestatus
And the code I have is:

```
import requests, json

# Skuvault URIs and Token
SkuBase = "https://app.skuvault.com/api/sales/getOnlineSaleStatus"
SkuProductsUri = SkuBase + "Products(id)/Attributes('name')"
SkuAuthToken = ""

print "[+] Requesting: " + SkuProductsUri

response = requests.post(SkuProductsUri, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + SkuAuthToken})
productsJson = json.loads(response.status_code)

print "[*] Status: %d\n[*] Reason: %s\n[*] Message: %s\n[*] Raw: %s\n\n" \
    % (response.status_code, response.reason, productsJson['Message'], response.text[:300])
```

I'm receiving the following error when trying to run the script

> [+] Requesting: https://app.skuvault.com/api/sales/getOnlineSaleStatusProducts(id)/Attributes('name')
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "test-api.py", line 11, in 
>       productsJson = json.loads(response.status_code)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/**init**.py", line 339, in loads
>       return _default_decoder.decode(s)
>     File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.14_3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
>       obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
>   TypeError: expected string or buffer

Like I said, I'd literally never worked with Python before this and feel a bit overwhelmed. Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could specify where the issue is. Or post the full error message.

Comment: Error code added, thanks.

Comment: I believe `status_code` that you are passing is an int, which is not a string or buffer that is required, maybe try `r.text`

Comment: I think the same, I think I need to change the whole line "productsJson = json.loads(response.status_code)" but I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: `productsJson = json.loads(response.text)` should work. Or you can get the json directly with `productsJson = response.json()`.

Comment: The documentation says the URL should be just `https://app.skuvault.com/api/sales/getOnlineSaleStatus`.  Why are you appending `Products(id)/Attributes('name')` to it?

Comment: @JohnGordon Like I said I have no idea, it was just a straight translation from what a coworker provided me. Should I just remove the SkuProductsUri variable? and just use SkuBase?

Comment: Yes I think you should just use `SkuBase`.

Comment: @JohnGordon great, got that updated. Now I'm getting this "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: Update your question to the current code you're using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not calling the API correctly. Notice that the API expects you to POST a request, and it expects the request payload to look like

```
{
  "OrderIds": [
    "my-id"
  ],
  "TenantToken": "my-tenant-token",
  "UserToken": "my-user-token"
}
```

If I were doing similar, I might do:

```
sku_base = "https://app.skuvault.com/api/sales/getOnlineSaleStatus"
response = requests.post(
    sku_base, 
    json={
      "OrderIds": [ "my-order-id" ], 
      "TenantToken": "my-tenant-token", 
      "UserToken": "my-user-token"
    }
)

# NOTE: you are not using the status code here. That's an int and will error.
productsJson = json.loads(response.text)
# This is also valid and will result in the same object:
productsJson = response.json()

print "[*] Status: %d\n[*] Reason: %s\n[*] Message: %s\n[*] Raw: %s\n\n" \
% (response.status_code, response.reason, productsJson['Message'], response.text[:300])
```

---

### Side note:

Python 2 is no longer maintained. It is recommended that you  use Python 3 exclusively.

Comment: _Python 2 is no longer maintained_ It's got a few years left :-).

Comment: see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0373/ which says: `Being the last of the 2.x series, 2.7 will have an extended period of maintenance. Specifically, 2.7 will receive bugfix support until January 1, 2020. All 2.7 development work will cease in 2020.`

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you guys so much for your help!